# See which boards are shared with which users in Trello

Tags: trello

I accidentally shared a some boards with the wrong Trello user.

I’ve tried to remember which boards I shared with them and tried to remove the wrong user manually from each of those boards. But I can’t remember exactly which boards I added them to.

I do remember the wrong Trello user username; is there someway I can search for all boards I own / I’m part of which are shared with a particular user?